# Automorphism group of a modular curve and its action on the set of cusps

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms

Let $X$ be a modular curve, that is the compact Riemann surface obtained by adding cusps to a quotient $Y=Y_\Gamma=\mathbb H/\Gamma$ of Poincaré upper half-plane $\mathbb H$ by a congruence subgroup $\Gamma$ of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$.  The latter can be one of the following subgroups 
$\Gamma(N),\Gamma_0(N)$ or  $\Gamma_1(N)$ of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$, for a certain positive integer $N$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup for a precise definition). Accordingly, I will denote $X$ by $X(N)$, $X_0(N)$ and $X_1(N)$ respectively.

**Questions:**

-- What is know about the automorphism group ${\rm Aut}(X)$ of $X$?

-- Same question for the automorphism group ${\rm Aut}(Y)$ of $Y$?

-- Does ${\rm Aut}(Y)$ act transitively on the set ${\mathcal C}_X$ of cusps of $X$?

-- If not, is there a description of the orbits (of the action of ${\rm Aut}(Y)$ on ${\mathcal C}_X$)?

(I'm mainly interested by the modular curves $X_1(N)$)

These are very natural questions but the literature on modular curves is… huge! 
Precise references would be welcome.

Comment: Why do you think that $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ preserves $\mathcal{C}_X$? This is certainly false when $X_1(N)$ has genus 0 or 1, which is the case for small values of $N$.

Comment: Probably the question is intended ask about automorphisms of the "open" modular curve, and/or automorphisms of the compactification that stabilize the _set_ of cusps...?

Comment: @ abx: you are right, the first version of my question did not make sense (for low genus modular curves)! Question edited, along the lines suggested by P. Garrett. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A trivial remark. When $\Gamma = \Gamma(N)$ the automorphism group contains the quotient $\Gamma(1)/\Gamma(N) = \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbf Z/N)$. It acts transitively on the cusps, since the quotient by the action is $X(1)$, which only has one cusp.

Comment: There is this paper: http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1988__65_1_51_0.pdf